# Enable alt-drag

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu

I am very used to alt-drag for moving and resizing windows.

However, I can't get it to work in xubuntu 13.10.  (I just recently installed it in a virtual box machine).  If I change it to a different key (shift for example), shift-drag works as expected.   When it is set up to use alt, and I press the alt key, it activates the menu shortcuts, but doesn't drag or resize windows if I click.

EDIT:

Yes, that sounds like exactly the setting I need to change.  However, when I pull up the keyboard settings, that tab isn't there.  I'm using xubuntu 13.10.

[image: screenshot of keyboard settings]

So where else might that setting live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem:

I am running inside a virtual box, and had Alt-dragging turned on in the host system.  Even though Alt-drag didn't drag the whole VB window, it disabled it in the guest OS.  If I turned it off in the host, it works as expected in the guest.

Answer (score 1):

Open the System Settings application, then go to Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Launchers. You can disable the "**Key to show the HUD**" which seems to prevent you to use the alt-drag:

[image]

Comment: And how do you activate Alt click for moving/resizing? Disabling the HUD key did not activate it, presumably it has to be activated somewhere else.

Comment: @terdon To activate the Alt click: Settings -> Windows Maganer Tweaks -> Accessibility.

Comment: @DavidOneill thanks but I don't have that on my 13.10. No Window Manager Tweaks and no Accessibility either. Do I need to install something?

Comment: @terdon are you using **xubuntu** 13.10?  Not straight ubuntu.

Comment: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/xfce4-settings/ is what you're looking for I think

Comment: @DavidOneill argh, yes, sorry. I'm on Unity, I hadn't noticed the Xubuntu tag.